# function which allocates memory for structs and writes in them

Tags: arrays, c, struct, malloc

I try to allocate memory for a struct types variables and write in the variables with a function. The function is reading an XML-File and doing its job just fine, but in the main I'm only able to get one struct right, the rest looks like not initialized variables.

I did a Edit I hope i didnt forgot something.

My struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct{
  xmlChar *name;
  int      id;
}s_config;
```

I use LIBXML2 and the functions looks like this:

```
#include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>

void read_xml(char *docname, s_config **cfgs, int *cfg_count){

 int counter = 0; 

 *cfg_count = 2;
 *cfgs = (s_config *) malloc( cfg_count * sizeof(s_config) );

 doc = xmlParseFile(docname);
 cur = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
 cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;

 while (cur != NULL){
   if(( xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"config")))
     cfgs[counter]->name = xmlGetProp(cur, "name");
   counter++;
 }

  for(int i=0;i<cfg_count ;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
      printf("%x ",cfgs[i].name[j]);
    printf("\n");
   }

}
```

The XML-File looks like this:

```
Root
  ->Node with name = "config"
      -> atribut with name = "name"
          -> data i want
  ->Node with name = "config"
      -> atribut whit name = "name"
          -> data i want

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<config name="ffffffffffff"/><config name="1204567890A0"></config>
<configuration>
```

My main looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

  int number_of_cfgs;
  s_config *cfgs;

  read_xml(argv[1],&cfgs, &number_of_cfgs);

  for(int i=0;i<number_of_cfgs;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
      printf("%x ",cfgs[i].name[j]);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The first struct which I printf in the main is right but all after look like not initialized variables.

Comment: `I reduced the function` Please don't. Please post a full [MCVE]. Remember about `#include` - recreating them is no fun.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] as well a minimal xml file so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't see `number_of_cfgs` being initialized in your `main()`. I also don't see you allocating memory for the individual `.name`s.

Comment: @KamilCuk I did a edit with the missing function part.

Comment: @DevSolar, number_of_cfgs is at the moment static and will be inilialized in the function, it is only declared in the main. How do i allocate the memory for the individual?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I did a edit, I hope this is helpfull.

Comment: Decide. Either `*cfgs = ` or `cfgs[counter]->` or `cfgs[i].`. One of them will not compile. Either `cfgs` is a pointer to an array, an array of pointers or a pointer to a pointer (to an array of 1 element). Mixing it makes no sense. | When compiling your code I get  ‘read_xml’: error: invalid operands to binary *`
`error: ‘doc’ undeclared (first use in this function)`
`error: ‘cur’ undeclared (first use in this function)`
`warning: comparison between pointer and integer`
`error: ‘*(cfgs + (sizetype)((long unsigned int)i * 8))’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?`

Comment: `cfg_count * sizeof(s_config) ` is invalid - `cfg_count` is a pointer to `int`. Please compile with `-Wall -Wextra` and preferable with `-Werror` and fix all warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main()`:

```
s_config *cfgs;

read_xml(argv[1],&cfgs, &number_of_cfgs);
```

You pass the **address** of `cfgs` and `number_of_cfgs`, so that `read_xml()` can change their value. This is correct.

```
void read_xml(char *docname, s_config **cfgs, int *cfg_count){

 *cfg_count = 2;
```

You set main's `number_of_cfgs` to 2. This is correct (if a bit backwards).

```
 *cfgs = (s_config *) malloc( cfg_count * sizeof(s_config) );
```

Here (and below) you use `cfg_count` (of type `int *`) instead of `*cfg_count` (of type `int`) as you probably intended. This is broken.

Assuming you used `*cfg_count`, you allocate memory for an array of `*cfg_count` / `number_of_config` structs, and assign the address of that memory to `*cfgs`. `cfgs` is the address of `main()`'s pointer, `*cfgs` is that pointer (now pointing to the allocated memory). This is correct.

```
     cfgs[counter]->name = /* ... */
```

This is wrong in at least two ways.

1. You handle `cfgs` as the array of / pointer to structs, when it actually should be `*cfgs`. `cfgs[0]` will (mis-)use the memory taken up by `main()`'s `cfgs` (the pointer itself, of type `s_config *`) as `s_config` (of type `s_config`), which already invokes UB. An access to `cfgs[1]` etc. will just make things worse.
2. You use `cfgs[counter]` (which should be `(*cfgs)[counter]`) as a pointer (`->name`) instead of a struct (`.name`).

My comment about no `malloc()` taking place for `.name` was made obsolete by your edit.